# How to manage a big amount of rest services?

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, service

Now I'm configuring a big amount of springboot services, but there are dependencies between some services I mean there are config services and business specific services, I tried to configure all with systemd(linux servers) but sometimes the config services can't start up in correct time, and the other services don't work, Are there a better way to configure or manage rest/soap services?, sorry if the question is silly maybe I don't know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Do all of the services need to live on the same machine? Maybe consider a solution like kubernetes to handle some of the deployment related constraints.

Comment: Also to note, you can define service dependencies within systemd and that will block services from launching until the requirements are satisfied

Comment: ESB (for SOA) and API Gateway(for REST API)  may help in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks @Hades I think that API gateway is that I looking for.